# How would I print an object's name as part of the JSON in Java's Jackson library?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to determine how to print out a JSON that looks like this, using Java's Jackson library:

```
{
    "status": {
        {
          "busStatus" : {
            "status" : null,
            "transactions" : "0",
            "retries" : "0",
            "failures" : "0"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm 95% there, but the outermost object is not currently being printed. This is what I'm currently getting outputted:

```
{
  "busStatus" : {
    "status" : null,
    "transactions" : "0",
    "retries" : "0",
    "failures" : "0"
  }
}
```

I have a Java class that looks like this:

```
public class DataClass {

    public StatusData status = new StatusData();
    public StatusConfig config = new StatusConfig();
    

    public class StatusData {
        public SerialStatus busStatus = new SerialStatus();
    }
    
    public class StatusConfig {
        
    }

    public class SerialStatus {
        public String status = null;
        public String transactions = "0";
        public String retries = "0";
        public String failures = "0";
    }
}
```

I'm printing this class to json using the code below:

```
private DataClass internalData;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
status = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(internalData.status);
```

Is there a way I can configure Jackson to print out the name of the object its serializing into the JSON?

Comment: You should convert `internalData`, not `internalData.status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution I was looking for, [from this website](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations).

I've gotten rid of the DataClass and now only have a StatusData and a StatusConfig class. I've included how the StatusData class would look below:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "status")
public class StatusData {
    String status;
    String transactions;
    // so on
}
```

To parse the class, I needed to add the JsonRootName annotation above, and also enable a feature on the mapper, as below:

```
private DataClass internalData;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE); // don't forget this!
statusText = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(statusObject);
```

---

Separately, if you'd like to deserialize a JSON like the one I had into a class like StatusData, do this:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
statusObject = mapper.readValue(statusText, StatusData.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to print `DataClass` instead of `StatusData`. Something like below:

```
private DataClass internalData = <initialize>;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String data = 
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(internalData);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I use my DataClass for 2 different JSON serializations. One serialization for DataClass.status, and one for DataClass.config. So I can't just serialize DataClass.

Comment: Then you manually need to remove the config before serializing the internalData. I donot see any other option around here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson Filter to control the serialization process, I think it should work with your use case, at least one way to do it.

Use the filter annotation and then create two different filters for your class, where you can define which field to skip, and use it with the ObjectMapper accordingly to convert the whole `internalData` object, so when you need to skip the status, use one filter and when you need to skip the config associate the other filter with the mapper, while always serializing the parent object. Which should give you the structure you want.

```
        @JsonFilter("filter_serializer")
        class User {
            public String v1;
            public String v2;
        }

        String[] fieldsToSkip = new String[] { "v1" };

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final SimpleFilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        filter.addFilter("filter_serializer",
                         SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(fieldsToSkip));


        User dtoObject = new User();
        dtoObject.v1 = "v1";
        dtoObject.v2 = "v2";
        String jsonStr =  mapper.writer(filter).writeValueAsString(dtoObject);
```